# Stack/Overlap Images from Foreach Loop

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code :

```
<?php foreach($results as $result) : ?> <img src='<?php echo BASE_URI; ?>/images/userImages/<?php echo $result->userPicture; ?>' class="pic-athlete" style="z-index:5; position:relative;"> <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This currently displays all the images in a line. I want them to stack slightly over each other i.e for the first image I want it to have a z-index of 5, for the next one in the foreach loop I want it to have a z-index of 4 and so on...
Does anyone know how to make this happen? Maybe I need to use something other than z-index? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `foreach` is just a loop, so you can create a variable that you can decrement upon each loop:

```
$count = 5

foreach ($results as $result) {
    <img src='<?php echo BASE_URI; ?>/images/userImages/<?php echo $result->userPicture; ?>' class="pic-athlete" style="z-index: <?php echo $count; ?>; position:relative;">
    $count--;
}
```

Do you want to place the images directly on top of each other? You may want to think about wrapping all the images in a div or other container with a relative position and then giving the images themselves absolute positions.

Comment: great - thank you @trevorj! i accidentally put the $count inside the function when i tried before...silly.